# Puzzle in finding wave function

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, wavefunction

I was told that the wave function has the format $v^2 \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}$, in which:

- $t$ is time.
- $x$ is the wave propagation dimension, and $v$ is the wave propagation velocity.
- $y$ is the wave oscillation dimension, so that $y(x,t)$ is the wave function.

Using the following diagram as an example:
[image]

I can see that the wave function satisfies $y(x,t) = y(x-vdt,t+dt)$.  Expand $y(x-vdt,t+dt)$ by Talor-series: $y(x-vdt,t+dt) = y(x,t) - \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} v dt + \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} dt + o(dt^2)$

I get: $v \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$, which also determines o(dt^2)=0.

**What is wrong?**

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the wave has to move in the $+x$ direction. What about the $-x$ direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "o(dt^2)=0."?

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong! Doesn't this look like one of the square roots of your original equation?

Comment: "o(dt^2)=0." is the typo for $o(dt^2)=0$

Comment: @CPW did you mean $0(dt^2)=0$ ?